# MAC address through ad hoc wifi

Tags: networking, wifi, mac-address

When I create ad hoc wifi network with shared Ethernet connection to router, does the router register only the ad hoc host MAC address or all MACs of devices connected to router via the ad hoc network? I assume only MAC of ad hoc host, but I'm not sure.

For example, I connect from laptop1 to laptop2 through ad hoc wifi, then connect to router through laptop2 shared Ethernet connection; does the router register MAC of laptop1 or laptop2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. If laptop1 is doing it as a bridge, it will appear to the router as if there is a switch with two computers. The router will have laptop2's MAC address.

Laptop1 might do it using NAT. That way, the router won't know about laptop2; laptop1 will take care of everything.